# MOSFET Switching losses using SIMETRIX

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, spice, pspice

I want to calculate the switching losses of a SiC MOSFET from STMicroelectronics. The manufacturer provides Spice models that I have incorporated into the Simetrix simulator (I don't have PSpice). My electrical circuit is a simple DPT with identical SiC devices in the half bridge configuration.

Once the simulation is running, I can visualize my drain current and voltage (green and red curves), but when attempting to integrate the switching power (drain current * drain voltage, represented by the blue curve), I encounter a peculiar integral shape.

I have no idea how to accurately estimate my turn-on/turn-off losses using this software.

Can anyone provide me with more insights on how to do it?

[image]

Comment: You have to multiply the instantaneous current \$i(t)\$ by the drain-source voltage, \$v_{DS}(t)\$ and this will give you the instantaneous power, \$p(t)\$. Average the result over a switching period and you have the total average power, including turn-on and -off losses plus conduction losses. If you want the energy in µJ for instance, I would still multiply current and voltage and then *integrate* \$p(t)\$. Place the cursors across the result with positions corresponding to the on or off transition and average between them, you have energy in joules. I believe this is what I would try.